# Emacs not loading org-agenda-files on startup

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-agenda

So i've put this in my emacs.org:

```
(setq org-agenda-files (list
        "~/todo.org"))
```

But whenever i close and reopen Emacs, my org-agenda is empty until i reload my config-File. 
Is there anything that i've missed? Also i've tried some "eval-after-load 'org" combinations but none of them have worked for me so far.
Some help or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You should put that into your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`.

Comment: Alright, i will try that out as soon as i get back to my Computer! Can you explain why this is actually relevant?

Comment: Unless configured to do so, emacs doesn't inspect `emacs.org`, but it inspects the files I mentioned.

Comment: Well, i actually have the init.el-file parse emacs.org.
However the problem was on my side of the table:
init.el is only parsed once per session; namely on startup, whereas emacs.org is set up to be manually reloaded.
In my init.el file, under the custom-set-variables there was a line saying `(setq 'org-agenda-files nil)` which disabled all org-agenda-files on startup! No idea where this was coming from, but that explains why manually reloading emacs.org did the trick. 
Removed the nil-line from init.el, now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

@Tim Hilt, thank you! Your own answer was the answer to my problem as well, so I'm making a real answer out of it for others. Apparently you and I both must have set the Org Agenda Files entry in the Custom (`M-x customize`) menu.

The solution is to erase this entry in the Custom menu so that your intended value in your startup file is not erased.

There are two ways to do this:

A) From @Stefan, to get to the Custom GUI menu in question quickly:

`M-x customize-variable RET org-agenda-files RET`

then click on the button `State` and choose Erase Customization.

B)

Before @Stefan cued me to (A), the easiest way I found was to find the custom set values which looks like this in my .emacs file (it might be elsewhere for you):

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
```

then below that find the line

`'(org-agenda-files nil)`

And delete that sucker! Restart emacs and you should be golden!

Comment: `M-x customize-variable RET org-agenda-files RET` should do the trick without having to edit the auto-generated code.

Comment: Great tip @Stefan thanks! I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my init.el

```
(defun my-find-org-agenda-files ()
"Find all agenda files."
(interactive)
(require 'org)
(dolist (f org-agenda-files)
  (find-file-noselect f)))
```

In my case call it manually when I want to, but you could call it as part of your init.el.  of you want to call it automatically, add:

```
(my-find-org-agenda-files)
```

Afterwards.

Note that this loads the files into buffers without switching to any of the buffers.

Comment: When you open the agenda (`C-c a a` if you use the [suggested key bindings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html#Activation) ), then org opens all the agenda files in any case, so I'm not sure why you have to open them manually.

Comment: That is fine of you want to see the agenda, which I rarely do.  Partly because it can be slow to bring up (I have a number of files with a lot of data).  My goal is usually just to start taking more notes and the agenda view doesn't help me with that.

Comment: Well, we can argue whether that is a proper use of `org-agenda-files` then (but not here: conversations in comments are discouraged), but please note that your "answer" does not answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using org mode for your init/emacs configuration, You can add this entry to the emacs.org , just replace with the actual location of your org file, which should be in the emacs.d (depending on system)

```
** Load emacs initialization file: 
    #+BEGIN_SRC key emacs-lisp
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-c i")
    (lambda() (interactive)(org-babel-load-file "~/emacs.d/emacs.org")))
    #+END_SRC
```

It is a babel code block that adds the binding `C-c i` for loading the emacs.org file.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer but the expected behavior for me would be to let emacs load my agenda-files on startup! So i'm going with @choroba 's answer, which works great for me.